# How to alternate color of the graphs between blue and white?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a list `D` containing 50 sub-lists. The number of elements in these sub-lists are decreasing. I visualize the list `D` by

```
for i, array in enumerate(D):
    plt.scatter([i]*len(array), array)
```

[image]

I have 50 functions taking values from `St_Sp`, and `Y` is a list containing 50 elements, each of them is the output of each function. I visualize these functions

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(Y)):
    ax.plot(St_Sp, Y[i])
```

[image]

---

I found that too many colors are not easy to eyes. I would like to ask how to alternate color of the graphs between blue and white? I mean the color of the functions and dots in `D` are white > blue > white > blue ...

Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

---

```
##### Import packages
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
import time
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##### Initial conditions
N = 100
lamda = 7
mu = 2
a = np.exp(-0.05)
r = - np.log(a).copy()
St_Sp = np.arange(- N, N + 1)
Card = St_Sp.shape[0]

##### Define infintesimal generator
def LL(x, y):
    if x == N or x == - N: re = 0
    elif x - y == - 1: re = lamda
    elif x - y == 1: re = mu
    elif x - y == 0: re = - (mu + lamda)
    else: re = 0
    return re

def L(x):
    return - LL(x, x)

##### Define function Phi
def Phi(x):
    return max(x, 0)
Phi = np.vectorize(Phi)

##### Define vector b
b = np.array(Phi(St_Sp))

##### Define function Psi
def Psi(x):
    return L(x) / (L(x) + r)
Psi = np.vectorize(Psi)

##### Generate a Boolean vector whose all elements are False
d = np.array([0] * Card).astype(bool)

##### Define matrix A
A = np.zeros((Card, Card))
for i in range(Card):
    for j in range(Card):
        if (i != j) & (L(St_Sp[i]) != 0):
            A[i, j] = LL(St_Sp[i], St_Sp[j]) / L(St_Sp[i])
        elif (i != j) & (L(St_Sp[i]) == 0):
            A[i, j] = 0
        elif (i == j) & (Psi(St_Sp[i]) != 0):
            A[i, j] = - 1 / Psi(St_Sp[i])
        else: A[i, j] = 1

##### Row names of A
rows = np.arange(0, Card)

##### Define matrix B
B = np.zeros((Card, Card))
for i in range(Card):
    for j in range(Card):
        if i != j:
            B[i, j] = LL(St_Sp[i], St_Sp[j])
        else: B[i, j] = LL(St_Sp[i], St_Sp[j]) - r

start = time.time()        

##### Generate I_0
I = [np.array([1] * Card).astype(bool), d.copy()]

Z = np.array(b.copy())
Z = Z.astype(float)       
D = [St_Sp]
index0 = np.matmul(B, Z) <= 0
index1 = ~ index0

Y = [b.copy()]

##### Iterations
for i in range(1, Card):    
    I = [I[0] & index0, I[1] | index1]
    Z = np.array(b.copy())
    Z = Z.astype(float)

    A1 = A[np.ix_(rows[I[1]], rows[I[1]])]    
    A2 = A[np.ix_(rows[I[1]], rows[I[0]])]

    Z[I[1]] = la.solve(A1, - np.matmul(A2, Z[I[0]]))

    Y = np.concatenate((Y, [Z]))
    D.append(St_Sp[I[0]])

    index = np.matmul(B[I[0]], Z) <= 0

    index0, index1 = d.copy(), d.copy()
    index0[I[0]], index1[I[0]] = index, ~ index

    if (I[0] == index0).all() == True: break

for i, array in enumerate(D):
    plt.scatter([i]*len(array), array)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(Y)):
    ax.plot(St_Sp, Y[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is to set a [custom color cycler](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html). Instead of cycling between the 10 typical colors, the default colors for the plots will cycle through the given colors.

```py
from cycler import cycler

custom_cycler = cycler(color=['white', 'blue'])
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(custom_cycler)
for i, array in enumerate(D[:-1]):
    plt.scatter([i] * len(array), array)
plt.scatter([len(D) - 1] * len(D[-1]), D[-1], color='crimson')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_prop_cycle(custom_cycler)
for i in range(len(Y) - 1):
    ax.plot(St_Sp, Y[i])
ax.plot(St_Sp, Y[len(Y) - 1], color='crimson')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Just a irrelevant question: do you have any suggestion and visualize such data?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand enough about the meaning of the data to give good visualization suggestions.

Comment: Actually, `D` is a list of sets in which `D[n+1]` is a proper subset (a refinement) of `D[n]`. I mean, after each iteration the set `D[n]` becomes smaller. In a similar way, after each iteration, the value of function `f_n` becomes larger. I want to visualize this evolution.

Comment: I mean the set `D[n+1]` is a refinement of `D[n]` and the function `f_{n+1}` is a refinement of `f_n`. The refinement is represented by the fact that `D[n+1]` is becoming smaller in the number of elements, while `f_{n+1}` becomes larger in values.

Comment: Hi @JohanC, my professor have just asked to have blue everywhere except that the last `D_n` is red. I hope you can help me modify your code to achieve this goal. Thank you so much for your help!